# PowerShell pipe ExpandProperty to another Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I want to get the aliases for all email recipients in my O365 tenant.
If I were doing this one traditional Exchange, the easiest is to `Get-Recipient` and pull out the SMTPAddress property using Exchange Manangement Console. (Note the Select piped into another Select; works like a champ.)

`Get-Recipient | Select Name,SamAccountName -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | Select Name,SamAccountName,SmtpAddress`

The issue is when I try to do the same thing in EXO, the "EmailAddresses" property is output as a flat string and so when I try to pipe it to a 2nd select, the only Property is the Length, not the actual value of the string.

The following kind of works, but I feel like there has to be a better way?

`Get-EXORecipient | Select Name -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | % {Write-Output "$($_.Name),$($_)"}`

Comment: can you show us the expected result? The wording is a little confusing and all you might need is a calculated property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `-ExpandProperty EmailAddresses` expands to are *strings*, as you state.

The additional properties that these strings are decorated with if you also pass (positionally implied) `-Property` arguments, such as `Name` in your example, *are* present, but will typically not surface unless you explicitly access them on the now-decorated output strings.

If you want output objects that contain each email address *as a property*, more work is needed.

```
Get-EXORecipient | ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($emailAddress in $_.EmailAddresses) {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      EmailAddress = $emailAddress
      Name = $_.Name 
      # ... add further properties of interest here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful...that also gives me a good way to regex out the "SMTP" and "SIP" that's always prefixed to the email alias. Too bad Get-EXOReceipient doesn't behave like the old Exchange module.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @NitrusCS. Note that the difference in behavior hinges only on whether the `-ExpandProperty` property _values_ are strings or non-primitive objects with properties. In both cases, whatever objects the enumerated values of the expanded property are are _directly_ decorated with the `-Property` properties.